# Android seekbar with custom progressDrawable

Tags: android, seekbar

my problem is that my progress bar progressDrawable is very good in portrait mode.
but if i turn the screen to landscape mode it repeats it with 3 or more time.

What i need is to strech the progressDrawable.

in portrait:
[image]

in landscape:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

anything i had to do is to setProgressDrawable programatically in the so the activity set it always when i'm changing the layout.

```
bmiSeekBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bmi_progress));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make **9-ptach-png** out of you image and mark your rounded corners and maybe the transition of your colors as non strechable. You find a short explaination [here](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2010/06/9-patches/) and [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) together with a tool